# Delete query in JPA gives errors

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I get some errors while I'm trying to delete something with delete query in JPA.

Here is remove function that is called in main package.

```
public void removeAppoinmentsFromDB(int idToDelete) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Programari WHERE idProgramari = :idToDelete");
    query.executeUpdate();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();        
}
```

I get this errors:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument idToDelete not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.processParameters(QueryImpl.java:579)

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:294)

at util.DatabaseUtil.removeAppoinmentsFromDB(DatabaseUtil.java:85)

at main.Main.main(Main.java:82)

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception. But what's the point of this query? Why not just use EntityManager.remove()? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove-java.lang.Object-

Comment: @JBNizet I should use delete queries as my teacher said, I've triend 5 minutes ago with remove and all works good, but i shoudl use query. Also link for trace: https://pastebin.com/1qnR6vh0

Comment: Post the stack trace (not a link, the stack race itself) in the question. Then post the actual code. The stack trace clearly shows that you are not executing the query that you posted. Then show the relevant code. What is PetHospital? What is programari? And finally, a parameter in a query starts with `:`: `WHERE idAppoinment = :idToDelete`

Comment: @JBNizet I edited the posted with new trace and code.

Comment: Post the stack trace (**not a link, the stack trace itself**) in the question. [...] Then **show the relevant code. What is PetHospital? What is programari?**

Comment: programari means appoinment in my language and it's a table, also PetHospital is the schema

Comment: You need to set the ID in your query to be deleted.  Something like `query.setParameter("idToDelete", idToDelete);  query.executeUpdate();`

Comment: I don't need the translation of programari. You're executing a query trying to delete an entity. Post the code of that entity. Otherwise, we have no idea what PetHospital and programari are, in terms of JPA code. And, for the 4th time now, post the stack trace in the question. Not a link to the stack trace. The stack trace.

Comment: @NicholasSmith this was the problem, thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome @Bogdy, posted as an answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the ID in your query to be deleted.

```
public void removeAppoinmentsFromDB(int idToDelete) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Programari WHERE idProgramari = :idToDelete");
    query.setParameter("idToDelete", idToDelete);
    query.executeUpdate();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();        
}
```